# add a transparent view into a translucent view

Tags: ios, zxing

I want a view like the picture attached, the full view's background is translucent, and the view in green frame is transparent.
I tried addSubview and set subview's alpha but it is not worked.

[image]

Comment: No picture attached though

Comment: @verbumdei sorry for forget it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override your drawRect method. Fill it all with translucent, then fill in the transparent part with clear color:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // fill it all with translucent
    [yourTranslucentUIColor setFill];
    UIRectFill( rect );


    CGRect yourMiddleHoleRect = CGRectMake(* calculate your rect here);

    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( yourMiddleHoleRect );
}
```

I think this will give you a cleaner result than other options.

You could even draw in those green frame indicators here if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to achieve that is to instead add 4 translucent views around your transparent view.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add the translucent view over the background view by **CGContextDrawImage**.
Then use **CGContextSetBlendMode** to clear the portion.

Refer the below project to achieve this.

https://github.com/akopanev/iOS-Scratch-n-See